# The name given to the number 1 in the context of Primes and Composites

Tags: prime-numbers

We give names to the sets of numbers called Primes and Composites. Is there a name for the number 1, in this context, seeing it is neither a Prime or Composite?

Comment: $1$ (and $-1$) are called units.  A prime can be defined as a number $p$ that is not a unit and is such that for any factorization $p=ab$ either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.  Elements which are neither prime nor units are composite.

Comment: This is weird but... 1 is a composite of itself, 1*1*1...*1 = 1 so why is not considered as a special case of composite number?

Comment: @iadvd - because $1$ is not prime.

Comment: @Joffan true! :) it leads also to the typical discussion about 1 being prime or not (which is not, I know...)